# How can I kick off a second webhost on a different port in visual studio during development

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to kick off a second webhost in asp.net core. Program.cs looks like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Start();
        CreateWebHostBuilder2(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5100")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder2(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5200")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

When I publish this and run it from the command prompt this is working. Both ports work.
I need this second webhost during development though and running this in visual studio the UseUrls part used in the webhostbuilder is ignored because iisexpress uses the applicationUrl set in launchsettings.json.

Is there a way to get around this so the second webhost listens to the other port (5200) during development?

Comment: Do you need to use IIS expross during development? In your project settings you can set the project to run in a console when you when you debug it.

Comment: Thanks Georgi, that solved it